# R `object not found` error dplyr select when variable is present

Tags: r, dplyr

getting this error for all dataframes / tibbles and can't figure out why.

R Version: 3.6.0
- I'm working out of a googledrive folder, but have been for months without issue. 
- it is a git-connected folder aswell
- I have some functions that use {{}} tidyeval, but I get the error with or without the functions

```
mtcars %>% rename(mpg2 = mpg)

Error: object 'vctrs_new_data_frame' not found
```

error shows:

```
<error/rlang_error>
object 'vctrs_new_data_frame' not found
Backtrace:
  9. dplyr::rename(., mpg2 = mpg)
 11. tidyselect::vars_rename(names(.data), !!!enquos(...))
 12. tidyselect:::rename_impl(NULL, .vars, quo(c(...)), strict = .strict)
 13. tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
 14. tidyselect:::with_subscript_errors(...)
```

backtrace shows:

```
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
object 'vctrs_new_data_frame' not found
Backtrace:
     x
  1. \-mtcars %>% rename(mpg2 = mpg)
  2.   +-base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  3.   \-base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  4.     \-base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  5.       \-`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
  6.         \-magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
  7.           +-base::withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
  8.           \-function_list[[k]](value)
  9.             +-dplyr::rename(., mpg2 = mpg)
 10.             \-dplyr:::rename.data.frame(., mpg2 = mpg)
 11.               \-tidyselect::vars_rename(names(.data), !!!enquos(...))
 12.                 \-tidyselect:::rename_impl(NULL, .vars, quo(c(...)), strict = .strict)
 13.                   \-tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
 14.                     \-tidyselect:::with_subscript_errors(...)
<parent: error/simpleError>
object 'vctrs_new_data_frame' not found
```

Any ideas? My code was working fine last week!!

Comment: Can you try `mtcars %>% dplyr::rename(mpg2 = mpg)%>% names#
 [1] "mpg2" "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"` as this is working for me

Comment: same error "object 'vctrs_new_data_frame' not found"

Comment: Looks like some env issues.  Do you always save env while exiting

Comment: no, never - but I can review my env settings

Comment: then, it is good.  I am on R 3.6.2 with the devel version of `dplyr`

Comment: maybe I'll update then and see if any difference

Comment: I would try reinstalling dplyr and all of its dependencies

Comment: @DiceboyT just reinstalled and updated to 3.6.2, no difference, same error. Any tips for debugging or even resetting my environment?

Comment: what is `packageVersion('vctrs')` ?

Comment: @RonakShah 0.2.3

Comment: I have `‘0.2.0’` and it works for me like others without any error. Not sure if that is the reason though.

Comment: yeah I'm getting this error all over the place...tempted to remove everything and start from the ground up

Answer (score 0):

[Got an answer](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4898) from the helpful tidyverse dev team which worked:

```
remotes::install_github("r-lib/vctrs")
```

Had to remove the LOCK file associated to vctrs, then it worked. Thanks all for your comments.